# How to install a Silverlight OutOfBrowser Application with shortcuts created for all users

Tags: silverlight-4.0, installation, out-of-browser, xap

I've a Silverlight Out of Browser application where I does installation like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\sllauncher.exe /install:[path to xap file] /shortcut:desktop+startmenu
```

This does create shortcut in the current user's desktop. But once another user logs in it wont be available in his desktop. As part of testing I copied the created exe into the public desktop. But still the another user wont be able run the application from his account. How can I configure so that it works in all user accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some work around on this and have made a blog post [here](http://zeitgeist90.wordpress.com/2011/12/13/to-create-a-silverlight-out-of-browser-application-for-all-users/)

Comment: You should mark your post as answer if that answered your question.